# pandas dataframe to csv quotation mark

Tags: python, csv, pandas, data-processing

I tried to convert a pandas dataframe to csv using

```
dataframe.to_csv('final_processed.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

Then I got the csv file which has 5 columns, the first column is text, I opened the csv file and found that some lines are starting and ending with quotation marks for the first column while others are not (showed below). I want all of them to start and end with quotation marks, what should I do? Thanks very much.

> "Pt come to ER with chest pain ..... PT/INR and PTT be check at 0324,
> PT/INR as 92 .5/8 .8 and PTT wa
> 249.",administer/monitor,notprescribe/order,administer/monitor,notadr
>
> "Patient wa see in office on 05/04/2015 ....... Thi wa catch by
> another caregiver and report to my clinic
> manager.",transcribe/prepare/dispense,notprescribe/order,notadminister/monitor,notadr
>
> Multiple medication enter on Med Rec by different provider with
> inaccurate dose and ......hospital
> admission,prescribe/order,prescribe/order,notadminister/monitor,notadr

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `quoting=True` to `dataframe.to_csv`as follows:

```
dataframe.to_csv('final_processed.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False, quoting=True)
```

You can find more details in the official documentation [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_csv).

---

Here's a fully working example

```
import pandas as pd 
from StringIO import StringIO 

st = """
"Pt come to ER with chest pain ..... PT/INR and PTT be check at 0324, PT/INR as 92 .5/8 .8 and PTT wa 249.",administer/monitor,notprescribe/order,administer/monitor,notadr

"Patient wa see in office on 05/04/2015 ....... Thi wa catch by another caregiver and report to my clinic manager.",transcribe/prepare/dispense,notprescribe/order,notadminister/monitor,notadr

Multiple medication enter on Med Rec by different provider with inaccurate dose and ......hospital admission,prescribe/order,prescribe/order,notadminister/monitor,notadr
"""
data =pd.read_csv(StringIO(st), delimiter=",", header=None) 
data.to_csv("final_processed.csv", encoding="utf-8", index=False, quoting=True)
```

The output looks like this:

```
 "0","1","2","3","4"
"Pt come to ER with chest pain ..... PT/INR and PTT be check at 0324, PT/INR as 92 .5/8 .8 and PTT wa 249.","administer/monitor","notprescribe/order","administer/monitor","notadr"
"Patient wa see in office on 05/04/2015 ....... Thi wa catch by another caregiver and report to my clinic manager.","transcribe/prepare/dispense","notprescribe/order","notadminister/monitor","notadr"
"Multiple medication enter on Med Rec by different provider with inaccurate dose and ......hospital admission","prescribe/order","prescribe/order","notadminister/monitor","notadr"
```

Comment: quoting=True: 
  File "pandas\core\generic.py", line 3020, in to_csv:     formatter.save()
  File "pandas\io\formats\csvs.py", line 170, in save:     self.writer = UnicodeWriter(f, **writer_kwargs)
  File "pandas\io\common.py", line 545, in UnicodeWriter:     return csv.writer(f, dialect=dialect, **kwds)
TypeError: "quoting" must be an integer

Comment: Did you mean `doublequote`?